# Meetings disappear from Outlook 2010 personal calendar

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, activesync, calendar

I have an issue where meetings are disappearing from a user's outlook 2010 calendar, seemingly caused by ActiveSync.

The workflow and issue are as follows:

User A has owner permissions on user B's calendar. User A creates a meeting and invites user B. User A accepts the meeting on behalf of user B. User B syncs their calendar to their phone using ActiveSync. 15 minutes later, the meeting disappears from user B's calendar.

When the email app on the user B's phone is set to not sync the calendar, the issue doesn't occur. There don't seem to be any settings on the phone (Samsung Galaxy s5), that could cause this behavior. Has anyone experienced this issue before, or know of a resolution? (Exchange version is 2010).

Comment: Sounds like the phone has priority over the server in the sync-ing process settings.

Comment: So there seems to be a setting on the device called "in case of sync conflict" that can be set to either "server has priority" or device has priority". Hopefully this will be the fix. I must have missed this going through the settings the first time.